# ReflectionException in Route.php line 335: Function () does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm tryin to get this grid (http://www.mariogallegos.com/tutorials/crud-custom-form) to work in Laravel 5.3.19.

I'm getting the exception:
ReflectionException in Route.php line 335: Function () does not exist

In my web.php i have the followingcode:

```
   Route::group(['middleware' => 'sidebarmenu'], function()
    {   
        Route::get('/home', [
    'as' => 'home',
    'uses' => 'HomeController@index'
        ]);

        Route::get('/users', [
       'as' => 'users', 
      GridEncoder::encodeRequestedData(new UserRepository(new User()),          Request::all())
        ]);

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your controller code with a function callback.

Replace

```
Route::get('/users', [
 'as' => 'users', 
 GridEncoder::encodeRequestedData(new UserRepository(new User()), Request::all());
]);
```

with

```
Route::get('/users', function() { 
  GridEncoder::encodeRequestedData(new UserRepository(new User()), Request::all());
})->name('users');
```

Comment: Hi Jedrzej, thanks for your reply. Sorry for my late reaction.